# How to check for string having only spaces in javascript

Tags: javascript

In my code i need to write an if else block-

```
when the variable `currentValue` is holding only spaces -> certain code
```

But i don't know how to write this condition as `currentValue` can be a string of any size. It can hold `" "`, `"    "`  etc.
if i write `currentValue!=" "` it checks for single space.

Comment: do you mean spaces (char 32) precisely, or any whitespace (end of line, tab etc)?

Comment: You should probably try Googling for something like `javascript match string`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Could look like

```
if( !currentValue.trim().length ) {
    // only white-spaces
}
```

docs: [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Even if its very self-explanatory; The *string* referenced by `currentValue` gets *trimmed*, which basically means all white-space characters at the beginning and the end will get removed. If the entire string consists of white-space characters, it gets cleaned up alltogether, that in turn means the `length` of the result is `0` and `!0` will be `true`.

About *performance*, I compared this solution vs. the *RegExp* way from @mishik. As it turns out, `.trim()` is much faster in FireFox whereas `RegExp` seems way faster in Chrome.

http://jsperf.com/regexp-vs-trim-performance

Comment: Maybe it's because of lack of support in IE < 9, perhaps. Who knows. It's simple to shim String.prototype.trim though, and even simpler to write a comment explaining the downvote.

Comment: The code is perfect, but does not "function right" in case of zero length string. So, if string contain no spaces at all, and the value is "", then it may be a complete different case. so: if( !"".trim().length ) { /* white spaces AND zero length string */ }

Comment: @Armen that might be a meaningful distinction,  but an empty string does contain only space characters.  That is,  every character in an empty string *is* a space character.

Answer (score 9):

Simply:

```
if (/^\s*$/.test(your_string)) {
  // Only spaces
}
```

To match `space` only:

```
if (/^ *$/.test(your_string)) {
  // Only spaces
}
```

Explanation: `/^\s*$/` - match a beginning of a string, then any number of whitespaces (space, newline, tab, etc...), then end of string. `/^ *$/` - same, but only for spaces.

If you do not want to match empty string: replace `*` with `+` to make sure that at least one character is present.

Comment: This matches the empty string too, and also newlines, and tabs.

Answer (score 0):

One can check if the string does not contain any non-whitespace characters with a regular expression. This method will only check each character at most once and will exit early as soon as it encounters a character that is not whitespace.

```
if(!/\S/.test(str)){
   console.log('str contains only whitespace');
}
```

One could also use [`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) to remove all whitespace from the beginning and end of the string. If the string only contained whitespace, the result will be an empty string, which is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

```
if(!str.trim()){
    console.log('str contains only whitespace');
}
```

If the string might be null or undefined, the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) can be used.

```
if(!str?.trim()){
    console.log('str is null or undefined, or contains only whitespace');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try-:

```
your_string.split(" ").length
```

**EDIT**:

```
var your_string = "               ";
var x = your_string.split(" ").length - 1;

if ( your_string.length > 0 && (your_string.length - x) == 0 ) {
    alert("your_string has only spaces");
}
```